# Is this a correct JSON format {"coord":{"lat":37.4056,"lon":-122.0775}}

Tags: java, json

I understand that the correct JSON format would be like:

```
{"coord":[{"lat":37.4056,"lon":-122.0775}]}
```

But I have a data coming to me in this format

```
{"coord":{"lat":37.4056,"lon":-122.0775}}
```

If this is a correct JSON format, how to parse it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

In `Json` the `{}` brackets indicates an object, while the `[]` ones indicates an array.

Your first example contains an array with one object containing `lat` and `lon` properties, the object is accessed by `data.coord[0].lat`.
Your second example is an object containing a object with `lat` and `lon` properties.
That is, no array, just an object. The object is accessed by `data.coord.lat`.

Both are correct json.

You pretty much parse them the same way, they will just be different types (the object or array under `coord`).

```
// Parse:
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsondatastring);
// Fetching the object:
JSONObject coord = obj.getJSONObject("coord");
// Or fetching the array:
JSONArray coords = obj.getJSONArray("coord");
```